# Why cant I run a function from a module imported into Python Shell?

Tags: python, shell

This is the code for the module called Test:

```
def scope_test():
    def do_local():
        spam = "local spam"

    def do_nonlocal():
        nonlocal spam
        spam = "nonlocal spam"

    def do_global():
        global spam
        spam = "global spam"

    spam = "test spam"
    do_local()
    print("After local assignment:", spam)
    do_nonlocal()
    print("After nonlocal assignment:", spam)
    do_global()
    print("After global assignment:", spam)
```

I then import the file into Python Shell using:

```
import Test
```

And then run the function scope_test():

```
Test.scope_test
```

I have also tried:

```
from Test import scope_test
```

but I received this error:
AttributeError: module 'Test' has no attribute 'scope_test'.
Can anyone help please? Many thanks.

Comment: Why are you defining functions within a function? Seems like `scope_test` must be a class, and the other functions must serve as class functions. It would be better if you could elaborate what is that you want to do.

Comment: It works for me , >>> import Test
>>> Test.scope_test
<function scope_test at 0x0000000003422E48>
>>> Test.scope_test()
('After local assignment:', 'test spam')
('After nonlocal assignment:', 'test spam')
('After global assignment:', 'test spam')

Comment: It works for me. I think maybe you have some other module named Test in your sys.path

Comment: you shouldn't get error

Comment: If the `import Test` is successful then run `Test.__file__` to see which file has been loaded as Test. If it is the correct file then make sure you have saved and updated the file after adding the function `scope_test()`

Comment: Also if you have imported Test before you added `scope_test()` in the file then rerunning `import Test` will not help. You have to either `reload` the module or better restart the python REPL and import again.

Comment: I was replicating the scope test example from Python 3 Tutorial doc. Rename the module to a different name did it for me. Thank you. (I tried a different name before and it did not work; but this new name works). @SigmaPiEpsilon: I ran .__file__ and it was the correct Test file. How can I check how many files have the same names in sys.path? My output is: >>>After local assignment: test spam>>>After nonlocal assignment: nonlocal spam>>>After global assignment: nonlocal spam